# How to disable page content using javascript when the form is submitted

Tags: javascript

In my application when i click form submit, service call happens. When the service call happens I need to I need to disable the page conetent til the next page loads.

As i have given cursor:wait the mouse pointer changes to loading symbol and does not allow to click on the page. But still i could use tab and enter or change the values in the page.

Can anyone tell the code to disable page content using transparent image?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that easier than with a transparent image :

```
$('body.waiting > *').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I think that you should only disable the submit input for example :

```
$('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

With a "overlay", add an absolute div at the top of your page :

```
<div id="overlay" style="position:absolute;background:url('trans.png');left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;display:none;"></div>
```

And than simply show it when your form is submitted :

```
$('#overlay').show();
```

Comment: $('body.waiting').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); })This is not working.

Comment: `body.waiting > *` try with this one, but it's not the best solution ;).

Comment: var d = document.getElementById("disabledLayer"); if (d) return; try { d = document.createElement("div"); d.id = "disabledLayer"; with (d.style) { backgroundImage = "url("/images/transparent.gif)"; backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"; cursor = "wait"; position = "absolute"; zIndex = 1000; margin = 0; left = 0; top = 0; width = "100%"; height = "100%"; } document.body.appendChild(d); d.focus()

Comment: I Tried with this code but still the page is disabled, then i tried using some other visible image with the same resolution of transparent. The image is not covering the full page so only the page is not disabled. Is anything wrong in the above code.